# pdfbox2.0.4 convert pdf with Chinese to png

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have imported **pdfbox-2.0.4.jar**, **fontbox-2.0.4.jar** and **commons-logging-1.1.1.jar** into eclipse kepler. The programm runs on win10.
The console prints lots of such warnings

```
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
WARNING: Using fallback font ArialUnicodeMS for CID-keyed TrueType font KaiTi_GB2312.
```

And I cannot access the image file with whole content. How can I fix it?
My code is like this:

```
public class PdfboxTest {
    private static final String filePath = "xxx";
    private static final String outputFilePath = "xxx";

    public static void change(File inputFile, File outputFolder) throws IOException {

        String totalFileName = inputFile.getName();
        String fileName = totalFileName.substring(0,totalFileName.lastIndexOf("."));
        PDDocument doc = null;
        try {
            doc = PDDocument.load(inputFile);
            PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(doc);
            int pageCounter = 0;
            for(PDPage page : doc.getPages())
            {
                BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageCounter, 300, ImageType.RGB);
                ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, outputFilePath + "\\" + fileName + (pageCounter++) +".png", 300);
            }
            doc.close();

        } finally {
            if (doc != null) {
                doc.close();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputFile = new File(filePath);
        File outputFolder = new File(outputFilePath);
        if(!outputFolder.exists()){
            outputFolder.mkdirs();
        }
        try {
            change(inputFile, outputFolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try installing the fonts that are missing, e.g. `KaiTi_GB2312`, this is from PDF files that didn't embed their fonts. Re `And I cannot access the image file with whole content` what do you mean, is this a permission problem or do you mean that chinese text is missing in the image?

Comment: Thank you for your edit suggestion and question advice. I have fix the problem by installing the font KaiTi_GB2312. And now I can get the image with whole content in pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the comments - the best solution is to install the missing font `KaiTi_GB2312`. The message `Using fallback font` means that the PDF references the mentioned font and didn't embed it, but can't find it on your computer, so PDFBox tried a fallback solution, in this case the `ArialUnicodeMS` font. Sadly such fallback solutions are not always perfect, which is why some glyphs were missing in the rendered image.